# Creating dynamic audio with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio

**Problem**

My application (morse code translator) takes user input and converts the text into sounds to be played on following the route. However, my current application will play only a single sound, and not more even if the method is called several times. And it plays it from the node process but not on the client. I feel like that requires creating some type of audio stream and then sending it to the user as part of a response, but I'll need some pointers on how to do that.

**Edit**

It appears that this isn't particularly easy, so I guess the cheating approach is just to have an audio file for each sound and then render an audio element for those given sounds.  I'd love to see a non-trivial example of how making audio through Node.js dynamically would work.

**Structure**

In my server, I attempt to invoke the functions which are the short audio outbursts, but only a single sound is evoked.

Server.js

```
var express    = require('express'),
    jade       = require('jade'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    morseCode  = require('./lib/translateMorseCode'),
    playSound  = require('./lib/playSound'),
    sfx        = require('sfx'),
    app        = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', './views');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

app.get('/translation', function(req, res) {
  var untranslated = req.query.input_text
  var translated = morseCode.translate(untranslated);
  var sounds = playSound.convert(translated);

  for (var i = 0; i < sounds.length; i++) {
     sounds[i]();
  }

  res.render('translation', { output: translated });
});
```

playSound.js

```
var sfx = require('sfx');

module.exports = {
  convert: function(translation) {
    var audioOutput = [];

    translation.split("").forEach(function(sound) {
        if (sound === ".") {
            audioOutput.push(function() { sfx.ping() });
        } else if (sound === '-') {
            audioOutput.push(function() { sfx.blow() });
        } else {
            audioOutput.push(function() { sfx.blow() });
        }
    });

    return audioOutput;
  }
}
```

I realize this solution isn't ideal, but I'm looking to just create a simple version of http://morsecode.scphillips.com/translator.html for learning nodejs.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to play the sound with [sfx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sfx), in nodejs, on the server, but rather to client who sent the request, on the client machine, as part of the response?

Comment: That's correct. I'm unsure of how to do that.  I feel like that requires creating some type of audio stream and then sending it to the user as part of a response. This was my first cut at trying to get audio to be produced. I'm open however to pointers on how to do that.

Comment: The way I see it, I either have to serve an audio clip of `.` and `-` multiple, varying times, or I have to create an audio stream and then serve that.

Comment: Producing a dynamic audio clip is probably easier than an audio stream, you should try that first. Of course, what is probably even easier, is to serve two static sound files for `-` and `.`, and [play them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) on the client using [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement).

Comment: To answer your question from the post before my edit, "*I'm looking to understand why the sound gets played but only once.*", that seems to be because playing a sound does take some time, and `sfx` is asynchronous. You're playing all the sounds in the `audioOutput` at once.

Comment: OK, but wouldn't I still need to create the `<audio>` element on the backend which would still vary depending on the input?  And then I would deliver the element.  But I still don't understand how to create audio on the backend. Even I have two separate audio files, I would at least need to join them together to generate the right sound.

Comment: You'd need to create two things on the backend: 1) the html file with the `<audio>` markup, including a link to 2) the audio file for the specific morse sequence. The audio file will be loaded by the browser with a second request. Yes, for this approach you would still need to concatenate your sounds. But I'm sure you'll find a lib for that as well, if you know what you're searching for (*manipulating sound files*, not *playing sounds*)

Comment: If you don't want to search for such a lib or can't find one, or think the two request thing is too complicated, that's what the second approach is for - just dynamically play multiple, single sounds (from two files `dit.mp3` and `dah.mp3`) using clientside javascript. This might be simpler, but would only work in modern browsers and users cannot download their morse sound file. Decide yourself what you need, what you want to learn (node or js in general?) and what is more fun.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Hey I know this is a few years too late. And this is largely for other users who might come across this. You might want to look at our API for this https://www.audiostack.ai/

I'd say you'd have something like a parameter https://docs.audiostack.ai/docs/dynamic-creative-optimisation-dco we call them personalisation parameters but you could have a list of these for morse code, and then when the morse code is sent you hear the audio associated for the morse code.

You'd still need to host a node server to serve this, but we built this to abstract away the challenges of serving audio dynamically - and as the writer of this post observed this can be quite tricky.